# Find out what triggers redraw in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-webview, android-jetpack-compose

In my Jetpack Compose app, I have an [`AndroidView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary#androidview) wrapping a [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView). While debugging, I see that the `WebView` is drawn twice (a breakpoint at the composable hosting the `AndroidView` is hit twice). After inspecting the code, I don't see any state updates that could be triggering this update.

Is there any strategy or tool to identify the "event" that is triggering the redraw of a `@Composable`?

Comment: This is not an answer but might help you:

//To observe when a re-draw happens and other info do:

private var I = 0
private var registerApplyObserver: ObserverHandle? = null

registerApplyObserver = Snapshot.registerApplyObserver { mutatedObjects, snapshot ->
        Log.i("TEST_TAG", "[${I++}] applying snapshot")
        for (obj in mutatedObjects) {
            Log.d("TEST_TAG", "[${I++}] state $obj modified")
        }
    }

Comment: Do you have NavHost in your code? If you have it might be recomposed because of it. It gets twice, sometimes more. I had a question  about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190119/jetpack-compose-recompose-with-success-state-twice-when-exiting-current-composab)

Comment: No, I was not using navigation in that project. Thanks anyway for the hint

Comment: This question was nearly 2 years ago, but Android Studio Dolphin (which is currently in Preview) has [Recomposition Counts](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#li-compose-counter) in the Layout Inspector that might be able to help you debug further!

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Now you can to identify what changes might have caused the recomposition just by usual debugging process with breakpoints.

This feature already available in the latest version of `Android Studio Hedgehog`

You can read more about this feature [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#compose-state-in-debugger)