# How to stop Jetpack Compose Navigation executing composable twice per click and why

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a Jetpack compose navigation as follows:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()

Scaffold(
    bottomBar = { /* BottomBar code here */ }
){ innerPadding ->

    NavHost(
         navController = navController,
         startDestination = "navigation",
         modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
    ){

        composable("home") { Log.d(TAG, "Show home screen") }

        composable("account") { Log.d(TAG, "Show account screen") }

        composable("settings") { Log.d(TAG, "Show settings screen") }

    }

}
```

My problem is when ever I click on a nav item, the log message on the `composable()` function is printed twice per click in logcat. I may have missed something on the documentation. Why is this happening & how can I fix it?

Comment: I asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190119/jetpack-compose-recompose-with-success-state-twice-when-exiting-current-composab?noredirect=1&lq=1), couldn't find an answer, instead of doing one shot request in Composable root, i decided to use `LaunchedEffect`.

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition

Comment: Have you tried to use 
 navController.navigate with navOptions? for example:
navOptions = navOptions {
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }

Answer (score 1):

You are in a typical case with side effects. Check compose documentation with the recomposition here :
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#parallel

Based on your code, if you want to display the debug log once when click on the "Display account button" :

```kotlin
val navController = rememberNavController()

Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("account") }) {
            Text(text = "Display account")
        }
    }
){ innerPadding ->
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "navigation",
        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
    ){
        composable("home") { Log.d(TAG, "Show home screen") }
        composable("account") {
            val isLogPrinted = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            if (!isLogPrinted.value) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Show account screen")
                isLogPrinted.value = true
            }
        }
        composable("settings") { Log.d(TAG, "Show settings screen") }
        composable("navigation") { Log.d(TAG, "Show navigation screen") }
    }
}
```

You can also put the log in your "onClick" function.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I cal solve it using [NavOptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavOptions.Builder)

```
 navController.navigate(
                ...,
                navOptions = navOptions {
                    launchSingleTop = true
                }
            )
```