# Jetpack Compose: pointerInput launch 2 times

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, gesture

I've been trying to allow navigation between multiple pages with a swipe gesture, like for example on Instagram when swiping to get to the messages. For this, I've used pointerInput with detectDragGestures:

```
.pointerInput(Unit){
                   detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                       change.consume()

                       if (dragAmount.x < 0){
                           navController.navigate(/* Route */)
                       }
                   }
            }
```

But when trying it, the navigate function seems be called 2 times, since when I use the back button I have to use it twice.

When removing this part of the code, obviously nothing happens.
The navigate function works correctly for this route since I have a button on the same page that calls it (like with the previous example with Instagram messages).
When changing the value of the amount needed for the function to be called, it only increases the length of the gesture, but still call the function twice.

Does someone see where this could be coming from ?

Comment: it is Intended Behaviour from the compose team. so there is no solution for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190119/jetpack-compose-recompose-with-success-state-twice-when-exiting-current-composab?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

detectDragGestures has few stages chose one to navigate

```
.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectDragGestures(
        onStart = { offset -> 
            // This is called when the drag starts.
        },
        onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
            // This is called while dragging. 
            change.consumeAllChanges()
            if (dragAmount.x < -someThreshold) {  // You can define someThreshold as a specific value, e.g., -100f
                navController.navigate(/* Route */)
            }
        },
        onStop = { 
            // This is called when the drag ends.
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: I have tried to put the navigate function in onDrag as you've shown but it still launches twice. In onStart or onStop I can't use dragAmount so I don't see how I could solve my problem :( Do you have another idea ?